# set curl request header for remote domain

Tags: php, json, curl

I am updating some fields in remote site using curl.  But I completed is:
I am able to logged in to remote site, able to fetch csrf token that I need to use in curl request. But I am not able to set header parameters as required in curl
test url is http://singh.mobi//vishal/curl/proposalform1.php

my code  is like:

```
            $ch1 = curl_init();

            $data_string = '{""proposal"":{""id"":36854,""name"":""New proposal #9"",""template_id"":5107,""sections"":[],""custom_tokens"":[],""reload_template"":true}}';

            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://alpha.niftyquoter.com/proposals/36854?cool_edit=true");

            //$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');     
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/home/brilliantmind/public_html/singh.mobi/vishal/curl/'.$cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/home/brilliantmind/public_html/singh.mobi/vishal/curl/'.$cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);                                                                 
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type: application/json', 'Origin: http://alpha.niftyquoter.com',                     'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',                                                          
                'X-CSRF-Token: $authenticity_token','Accept: application/json','Referer: http://alpha.niftyquoter.com/proposals/36854?edit=true'

            )                                                                         
            );                                                                                                                   

            $result = curl_exec($ch1);
            $header     = curl_getinfo( $ch1 );
            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($header);
            curl_close($ch1);
            echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the issue, error is in this line  'X-CSRF-Token: $authenticity_token' 
need to pass $authenticity_token outside of single quote.